# Using a txt file in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, import, information-retrieval

I have a tab delimited .txt file, which contains the date and other information related to the date eg

```
Calendar Date   Calendar Week   Calendar Period Calendar Year   Day No  Week    Day Of Week Day Of Month    Day No Sort Seq Important Day   Working Day
2003-01-01  1   1   2003    1-Jan   W01 Wed 1   1   1   1
```

What I need to do is put all of this data into an SQL Server database and then write a function to return the number of `Working Days` and `Important Days` there are in a particular month or time period. What is the best way for me to organize this data and how can I write the select statement to get the information I need ?  ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for bulk insert, if your file is really large.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx

But if it is not large, and this data is not needed after, I would just parse the file and calculate needed stuff on the run.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a once off job then:

1. Open the text file in Excel, and copy the rows to the clipboard.
2. In SQL Management Studio create a new table with the same number of columns.
3. Right click the table, choose Edit Top 200 Rows, and paste the rows in the results grid.

Comment: I'll have to query the DB that is created from this .txt file roughly three times a day; it is a once off job otherwise. Thanks a lot for the help.